Can I easily parse datetimes independently of my machine?
In python I like the datetime module of the standard library to parse timestamps.
However, some of the format codes depend on the locale set for the machine where it's run, which makes the code fragile:
from datetime import datetime

string = "08 Aug 2024 01:45 PM"
fmt = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p"

datetime.strptime(string, fmt)  # on an American computer
# datetime(2024, 8, 8, 13, 45)

datetime.strptime(string, fmt)  # on an French computer
# ValueError: time data '08 Aug 2024 01:45 PM' does not match format '%d %b %Y %I:%M %p'

Note: The equivalent in French is 08 aoû 2024 01:45  (different month name and no AM/PM)
Is there a more robust way to systematically parse timestamps?

At the moment, I went with a context manager setting my locale temporarily to fully control the process, but it feels like I'm missing a better tool for doing the same job.
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def locale_context(locale: str):
    import locale as l

    saved_loc = l.getlocale()
    l.setlocale(l.LC_ALL, locale)
    try:
        yield l.getlocale()
    finally:
        l.setlocale(l.LC_ALL, saved_loc)

def strptime(x: str, fmt: str, *, locale: str) -> datetime:
    """An equivalent of the standard strptime, with a way to fix the locale."""
    with locale_context(locale):
        return datetime.strptime(x, fmt)

strptime(string, fmt, locale="en_US")  # on an American computer
# datetime(2024, 8, 8, 13, 45)

strptime(string, fmt, locale="en_US")  # on an French computer
# datetime(2024, 8, 8, 13, 45)


@JonSG It doesn't that's the point of the question. I don't want to care about my currently set locale when parsing a timestamp.

What is wrong with setting the locale? You can also set locale globally for the process. It is what the locale is for. I don't want to care about my currently set locale when parsing a timestamp I do not understand. You want to write your own function to parse timestamp that does that? Some C standard libraries have also strptime_l that takes locale as an argument.

The problem with setting the locale is that my application becomes stateful, with all the complications that come with it. Everything else being equal I would prefer to keep it purely functional and machine-agnostic. My typical go-to way of making a stateful API stateless are context managers as I'm doing at the moment.

@Kamil "Some C standard libraries have also strptime_l that takes locale as an argument." - So OP could write their own extension module using it, yeah?

isn't the problem here that you have localized datetime strings in the first place? If they would be ISO8601 compatible for example, you would not have to care about setting a locale at all. Nonetheless, I also don't see much being wrong with setting a locale.

@FObersteiner You are absolutely right, this would be easier if the strings I was passed weren't localized. Unfortunately, this code is fed external data I don't have control of.

Related: Locale date formatting in Python, especially Piotr's answer, which links to Using Python locale or equivalent in web applications?, especially Alex Martelli's answer. They mention the library Babel, but it only seems to do output, not input.
